# Nhibernate Class mapping appending "_id" to the column name

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have two tables in my database Question and LanguageCode

Following is the structure for **Question** Table :

```
QuestionId int
Text varchar(100)
LanguageCode uniqueidentifier
```

Following is the structure for **LanguageCode** Table :

```
Id uniqueidentifier
Name varchar(20)
```

Now i want to map these two entities using NHibernate for that i created the Question & LanguageCode entity :

**Question Entity:**

```
public class Question
{
    public Question()
    {           
    }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Text { get; set; }

    public  virtual LanguageCode LanguageCode { get; set; }
}
```

**LanguageCode Entity:**

```
public class LanguageCode
{
    public LanguageCode()
    {

    }
    public virtual  Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual  string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Below are the mappings for these two entity classes

**QuestionMap :**

```
internal class QuestionMap : ClassMap<Question>
{
    public QuestionMap()
    {
        ReadOnly();
        Table("Question");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(x => x.Text);
        HasOne(x => x.LanguageCode);
    }
}
```

**LanguageCode Map:**

```
internal class LanguageCodeMap:ClassMap<LanguageCode>
{
    public LanguageCodeMap()
    {
        ReadOnly();
        Table("LanguageCode");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

Now on executing the following code :

```
LanguageCode languageCodeAlias = null;
Question question = null;
var res = session.QueryOver(()=>question)
                               .JoinAlias(() => question.LanguageCode, () => languageCodeAlias)

.WhereRestrictionOn(x=>x.Id).IsIn(questionIds).List();
```

I am getting an SQLException and below is query being created on execution :

```
 SELECT this_.Id as Id1_1_, this_.Text as Text2_1_1_,
 this_.LanguageCode_id as Language5_1_1_,
 languageco1_.Id as Id0_0_, languageco1_.Name as Name0_0_ FROM
 [Question] this_ inner join [LanguageCode] languageco1_ on
 this_.LanguageCode_id=languageco1_.Id WHERE this_.Id in (157827)
```

As it is clearly seen that instead of table name **LanguageCode** it is using **LanguageCode_id**, i have no idea how to resolve this.
So please help me with this issue and let me know if any more details is needed.

Comment: You need to specify the column name for `HasOne`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i figured out the solution by added the following class :

```
public class CustomForeignKeyConvention : IReferenceConvention
{
    public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Column(instance.Class.Name);
    }
}
```

And configured it in SessionFactory :

```
Fluently.Configure()
             .Database(ConfigureDb())
             .Mappings(m=>m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<QuestionMap>(cfg)
             .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<CustomForeignKeyConvention>()))
             .BuildSessionFactory();
```

If the column name is something like "columnname_abc" then we can change the

> instance.Column(instance.Class.Name) to instance.Column(instance.Class.Name + "_abc");

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `HasOne` I would use a [proper reference](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#references--many-to-one).

```
internal class QuestionMap: ClassMap<Question>
{
    public QuestionMap()
    {
        ReadOnly();
        Table("Question");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(x => x.Text);
        References(x => x.LanguageCode).Column("LanguageCode");
    }
}
```

`HasOne` is for [one-to-one special cases](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#hasone--one-to-one) and I would expect you to have many Questions using the same LanguageCode.

Comment: No luck !
I dont have LanguageCodeId column.

Comment: How do you link LanguageCode to a Question? You should have some foreign key.

Comment: yes, but the problem is the query is appending "_id" to languagecode column it should use "languagecode" instead of "languagecode_id".

Comment: Well, then use your column name in the mapping.

Comment: And the query that is being issues is the same?

Comment: Yes it issues the same :-|

Comment: If your mapping code is the same as in my updated answer, there is no place where `LanguageCode_id` can come from